# Mapping a 2D object to 3D space, maintining 2D size

Tags: actionscript-3, papervision3d

I have a papervision3d sphere primitive that I am adding to a scene.  The sphere is being sized with a radius of 285.  However, because of my camera properties (zoom, focus and z) the sphere is rendering at 206px instead of 570px which is what I want (2 * radius).

A while back I found a blog post concerning this very issue and it was explained that you can set the z of any object in the scene to appear in 3D space the same size it would appear in 2D space by using the following:

```
mySphere.z = (this.camera.zoom * this.camera.focus) - Math.abs(this.camera.z) + radius;
```

The above worked when I was using several blocks, where radius was replaced with width/2.  For some reason this does not work for the sphere.

Any ideas, pointers on how to get a sphere with a 570px diameter to show up on screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved, at least not precisely. The perspective projection does not map a sphere to a circle. See how the spheres at the edges of this image are getting deformed?
[image: grid of spheres]
<sub>(source: [uni-stuttgart.de](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/depthcue/spheres_saturation_big.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I see exactly what you are talking about. But in my situation I have a single sphere, like the one in the middle of your lattice (the red one).  That seems to map to a circle like I want to do - I just need it to be a fixed size.

Comment: Ha, I completely missed your response for 9 years. Sorry about that.

If your formula works for other objects but not sphere (I assume flat objects?), imagine you are drawing a flat circle on the screen. If you can get that working okay, note the radius of the circle (r), and distance of the circle from the camera position (d). Then you need to correct the sphere radius (make it smaller) so that the sphere is tangent to the cone whose base is the circle and tip is the camera position. The new radius is r' = r*d / sqrt(r^2 + d^2)

Comment: thanks so much for the response.  My boss has been on me about figuring this out and I have really started to feel like I was out of time on this.  It's been 9 years of "I think I can have it done next week" type excuses.  Thanks again!